# Sed, how to replace a string with a variable and string combination?

Tags: bash, variables, sed, substitution

The codeline below adds two different fixed-strings to beginning, and end of a line.

```
sed -i 's/.*/somefixedtext,&,someotherfixedtext/' ${f}

somefixedtext,20,30,10,50,someotherfixedtext
```

I want to enhance the output by using a variable, to give me below, instead of whats above;

```
HELLO,somefixedtext,20,30,10,50,someotherfixedtext
```

Tried some variations but all failed;

```
VARIABLE="HELLO"
sed -i 's/.*/"$VARIABLE,somefixedtext,&,someotherfixedtext/' ${f}
```

How can I incorporate a string variable to beginning of the line, combined with a fixedstring, in Sed ?

Answer (score 4):

Sed is a poor choice if the replacement string is from a variable, because it treats the variable as a sed command and not as literal string, so it will break if the variable contains special characters like `/` or `&` or similar.

Awk is better suited for this task, for example like:

```
$ cat file
20,30,10,50

$ var=hello

$ awk -F, -v prefix="$var" -v OFS=, '{print prefix, "sometext", $0, "somethingelse"}' file
hello,sometext,20,30,10,50,somethingelse
```

For inplace modification you will need a recent version of GNU awk, and the `-i inplace` arguments.

For what it's worth, the command would appear to work if you double quoted the variable, outside the single quotes, but it would be a bit buggy:

```
VARIABLE="HELLO"
sed -i 's/.*/'"$VARIABLE"',somefixedtext,&,someotherfixedtext/' ${f}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the Sed version works very well. These two single quotes ate my 2 hours :)